# jQuery: Server Side Code and Erroreems 

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is a quite straight forward jQuery code I find on one site:

```
//It simply loads more news
  function ReadMore(page){
       $("#news-list").html('Loading More News...');
       $("#news-list").append('<img src="/images/loading.gif">');   
        next=parseInt(page)+1;      
        html=$.get('/morenews.php','page='+page,function (data){                
            $("#News").append(data);
            $("#news-list").html("<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='ReadMore("+next+");'>More News</a>");
        });         
}
```

My question is:

1. What kind of datatype is it using? "Expected data type of the response. One of: null, 'xml', 'script', or 'json'. "
2. What is `html=$.get('/newread.php','page='+page,function (data){}` in jQuery? I have never seen `$.get` and there seems to be one parameter `page`.
3. Does the server receive something like this: /morenews.php?page=3
4. This code cant deal with errors. If the server is too busy, let's say, doing nothing for 20 seconds, how can I add some error messages?

By the way, jQuery seems to be a weird language because it constantly create anonymous functions.

Comment: jQuery is not a language but rather a JavaScript library. [Reading through the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) would probably be a good start, specifically [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: If you vote-down a question you should say why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `page` is an integer (although it gets typecast to a string when sent to the server as part of an HTTP GET request). `data` is an html string.
2. See [`jQuery.get( url , data , success() )`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). It's shorthand for $.ajax(). The `success()` function is a callback, which gets exectuted once a response is received from the server.
3. Yes: /morenews.php?page=3
4. You could try adding a timeout function to cancel the request if there's been no response within a given time.

The language is [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) (jQuery is just a library), and anonymous functions are really cool when you get used to them...

Comment: timeout function? Any examples or documentation?

Answer (score 0):

get() is used by jQuery to load data from a server using an HTTP get request. There's also a .post() method to use a post request, etc.

More info on .get() can be found here.....

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/